# Retrieve images in recyclerview from Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, data-retrieval

I am trying to retrieve images from Firebase Firestore. I am able to retrieve text in RecyclerView successfully however I'm not sure how to retrieve the images.

I had a look at similar questions unfortunately none helped.

**ListActivity :**

```
    //initialize firestore
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    //initialize views
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.resultRecycle);
    //set recycler view properties
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //show  data in recycler view
    showData();
}

private void showData() {

    db.collection("Item")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    //called when data is retrieved
                    //show data
            for(DocumentSnapshot doc: task.getResult()){

                        Model model = new 
                    Model(doc.getString("id"),
                                doc.getString("Title"),
                                doc.getString("Location"),
                                //STUCK HERE
                        );


                        modelList.add(model);
                    }

                    //adapter
                    adapter = new CustomAdapter(ListActivity.this, modelList);
                    //set adapter to recycler view
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });
```

**CustomAdapter :**

```
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            //this will be called when user clicks an item

            //show data on toast when clicking
            String title = modelList.get(position).getTitle();
            String location = modelList.get(position).getLocation();
            String  url = modelList.get(position).getUrl();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            //this will be called when user clicks long item
        }
    });

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int i) {
    //bind views /set data
    holder.mTitle.setText(modelList.get(i).getTitle());
    holder.mLocation.setText(modelList.get(i).getLocation());
    Picasso.get().load(modelList.get(i).getUrl()).into(holder.mUrl);

}
```

Please see the image below link, thank you 
[image]

Comment: Can you post the url of image and Database structure ?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Ashish please see the screenshot above

Comment: @Neha You sure that image url you have provided can not work until you have image in your storage at the same location it is shown in Firebase database.

Comment: @Ashish sorry dint get you

Comment: The url you have provided in your Database. It is location of image in storage so it won't work on any other until the same image and same location is available.

Comment: Is there a way i can store it in a proper way?@Ashish

Comment: @Neha i suggest to use Firebase Storage and update the url of database.

Comment: I am currently using Firebase storage to upload the images..@Ashish

Comment: Join [Chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198592/helping-others). It's getting too big in comment.

Comment: Cant join until i have 20 reputation unfortunately @Ashish

Comment: Then please post the code you have tried for Store the url of Image in Database and upload image code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198867/discussion-between-ashish-and-neha).

Comment: why dont you do `doc.getString("Img");`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad it returns listview without any images

Comment: @PeterHaddad Please check her database structure. It is location of image in Android Device.

Comment: yes i know it is the location in android device, was just asking why doesnt she do `doc.getString("Img");` to retrieve it

Comment: @PeterHaddad i think she tried yet her images not loading in the Glide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fileuploader code to upload the image in Firebase Database.

But make sure you put the Fileuploader run on the click of any button. Or it will throw nullpointer Exception if your edittext are empty.

```
private void Fileuploader(){ 
    if(imguri != null ) { 
        StorageReference ref = mStorageRef.child("Item"); 
        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        ref.putFile(imguri) 
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() { 
                @Override 
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { 
                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Image uploaded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
                        Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                        saveData(downloadUrl); 
                    } 
                }) 
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { 
                @Override 
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) { 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    } 
            }); 
    } 
}
```

The function will automatically start when file upload successfully done.

```
private void saveData(Uri imguri) { 
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>(); 
    EditText title = findViewById(R.id.etv_1); 
    EditText shortDesc = findViewById(R.id.etv_2); 
    TextView location = findViewById(R.id.etv_3); 
    String eTitle = title.getText().toString(); 
    String eShortDesc = shortDesc.getText().toString(); 
    String eLocation = location.getText().toString(); 
    String eUrl = imguri.toString(); 
    userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(); 
    getCate(); 
    data.put("Img", eUrl); 
    data.put("Title", eTitle); 
    data.put("Location", eLocation); 
    data.put("Short Description", eShortDesc); 
    data.put("Category", cate ); 
    data.put("id", userid); 
    db.collection("Item").add(data); 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully saved your item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class); 
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: please see the image for the database structure for image after updating the code above

Answer (score 0):

I have an best example of Retrieve images in recyclerview from Firebase Firestore ..link is here ...

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-example/

in this website given best hint and tutorial here.. please do follow step by step ...

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think this may hep using Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context).load(ImageURL).into(imageView);
```